# Import csv in Rapidminer is not loading data properly

Tags: rapidminer

Importing **csv** in **Rapidminer** is not loading data properly in the attributes/ columns and returns errors.

I have set the parameter values correctly in the 'Data Import Wizard'.

Column Separation is set to comma and when I check the "Use Quotes" parameter I see that there are too many "?" appear in the columns even though there is data in the actual csv file.

And when I do not check the “Use Quotes” option then I notice that the content of the columns are distributed across different columns, i.e., data does not appear in the correct column. It also gives error for the date column.

How to resolve this? Any suggestions please? I saw a lot of **Rapidminer** videos and read about it but did not help.

I am trying to import twitter conversations data which I exported from a 3rd party SaaS tool which extracts Twitter data for us.

Could someone help me soon please? Thanks, Geeta

Answer (score 1):

It's virtually impossible to debug this without seeing the data.

The `use quotes` option requires that each field is surrounded by double quotes. Do not use this if your data does not contain these because the input process will import everything into the first field.

When you use comma as the delimiter, the observed behaviour is likely to be because there are additional commas contained in the data. This seems likely if the data is based on Twitter. This confuses the import because it is just looking for commas.

Generally, if you can get the input data changed, try to get it produced using a delimiter that cannot appear in the raw text data. Good examples would be `|` or `tab`. If you can get quotes around the fields, this will help because it allows delimiter characters to appear in the field.

Dates formats can be handled using the data format parameter but my advice is to import the date field as a polynominal and then convert it later to date using the `Nominal to Date` operator. This gives more control especially when the input data is not clean.

Comment: Thanks for the response awchisholm (Sorry I don't know your name. Hence, addressed you with the username I see)

Comment: Thanks for the response awchisholm (Sorry I don't know your name. Hence, addressed you with the username I see). Is there a way I can attach the sample data file or Rapidminer screenshots to this chat for your reference? Only some of the rows in the csv file have double quotes in the twitter conversations column. So, not sure whether to select the use quotes option or not. When I saved this csv file as a tab delimited text file the commas issue is resolved but not the quotes. Please advise. I will try the nominal to date operator once i can get the read csv to work.